# Error in importing geojson polygon into RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

I have following [geojson polygon](https://gist.github.com/tekoadjaib/9e0f0729c050b69b283f) JSON that I'd like to import into rethinkDB. I attempted to use following `r.geojson` approach to import (refer to [Building an earthquake map with RethinkDB and GeoJSON](http://rethinkdb.com/blog/earthquake-geojson/)):

```
r.db("strongloop").table("region").insert(
r.http("91231cd2.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_REGION_WEB_PL_FLAT.json")("features")
.merge(function(zone) {
  return {
    zone: r.geojson(zone("geometry"))
  }
}))
```

This approach gives me following error:

```
RqlRuntimeError: Invalid LinearRing.  Are there antipodal or duplicate vertices? Is it self-intersecting? in: r.db("strongloop").table("region").insert(r.http("91231cd2.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_REGION_WEB_PL_FLAT.json")("features").merge(function(var_63) { return {zone: r.geojson(var_63("geometry"))}; }))
```

I suspect it is because the geojson comes from flattened multipolygon (done using [geojson.io Meta feature](http://geojson.io/) since RethinkDB does not support multipolygon) - but visually, the polygon is what I expected. I've also attempted to use `r.polygon` approach as following:

```
r.db("strongloop").table("region").insert(
r.http("91231cd2.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_REGION_WEB_PL_FLAT.json")("features")
 .merge(function(zone) {
  return {
    zone: r.polygon(zone("geometry")("coordinates"))
  }
}))
```

but RethinkDB expects me to give array of points

```
 RqlCompileError: Expected 3 or more arguments but found 1 in: r.db("strongloop").table("region").insert(r.http("91231cd2.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_REGION_WEB_PL_FLAT.json")("features").merge(function(var_64) { return {zone: r.polygon(var_64("geometry")("coordinates"))}; }))
```

I could not figure out how to extract array of geometry coordinates before passing to `r.polygon` using code above.

How should I resolve this? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check URL**

What happens if you do the `http` request by itself? I tried it and g0t a 404 on that resource. I would run that command first and make sure it works:

```
r.http("91231cd2.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_REGION_WEB_PL_FLAT.json")
```

**Try `r.args`**

`r.polygon` expects 3 arguments, but you're passing it one. You might try using `r.args` to spread those arguments in the function (similar to `Function.apply`, if you're a JavaScript guy)

```
r.db("strongloop").table("region").insert(
  r.http("91231cd2.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_REGION_WEB_PL_FLAT.json")  ("features")
   .merge(function(zone) {
    return {
      zone: r.polygon(r.args(zone("geometry")("coordinates")))
    }
  }))
```

**Invalid Polygons**

It seems that one of your polygons might be invalid. If you use the input from the other answer you posted and you use it the following function, it will work:

```
r.expr(ARRAY_FROM_OTHER_ANSWER_WITH_POLYGONS).do(function (arr) {
  // Remove middle element
  return arr.slice(0, 2).add(arr.slice(3, 5))
  // Map all elements to polygons
  // Make sure you pass an array of LON/LATs into `r.polygon`
  .map(function (row) {
    return r.polygon(r.args(row('geometry')('coordinates')(0)));
  });
})
```

Perhaps you can insert them one by one and catch the ones that failed.

The folowing query fails:

```
r.json(r.http('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tekoadjaib/9e0f0729c050b69b283f/raw/6950765ed4a931b9b208e69a3c39b3114be5c7e3/map.geojson'))('features')
  .map(function (row) {
    return r.polygon(r.args(row('geometry')('coordinates')(0)))
  })
```

While this one (slicing the first 17 elements) doesn't.

```
r.json(r.http('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tekoadjaib/9e0f0729c050b69b283f/raw/6950765ed4a931b9b208e69a3c39b3114be5c7e3/map.geojson'))('features')
  .slice(0, 17)
  .map(function (row) {
    return r.polygon(r.args(row('geometry')('coordinates')(0)))
  })
```

Comment: Hi Jorge, r.polygon still refuses r.args approach: 

    `RqlRuntimeError: Expected 3 or more arguments but found 1 in:
r.db("strongloop").table("region").insert(r.http("6h822726.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_PLNG_AREA_WEB_PL_FLAT.json")("features").merge(function(var_56) { return {zone: r.polygon(r.args(var_56("geometry")("coordinates")))}; }))1` - the `r.http` works fine. I use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create tunnel to my localhost and serve geojson remotely hence the URL is random and temporary

Comment: Can you post (in your answer) the result of the data you'd be inserting into `r.polygon`. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, the problem lies in the imported data. Both `r.geojson(zone("geometry"))` and ` zone: r.polygon(r.args(zone("geometry")("coordinates")(0)))` works. I can't verify which point that causes the error, but the error message seems similar with http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153573/points-of-linearring-do-not-form-a-closed-linestring-one-point-intersection. To solve this, I use http://www.mapshaper.org/ to simplify the polygon, then manually remove those with `geometry: null` - would be great if such filter / preprocessing can be done using rql as well

Answer (score 0):

Running this command on RethinkDB Data Explorer

```
r.http("6f892736.ngrok.io/data/geojson/MP14_REGION_WEB_PL_FLAT.json") ("features")
```

I received (removed some to fit SO limit)

```
 [
{
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    103.84874965353661,
                    1.363027350968694
                ],
                [
                    103.84924291873233,
                    1.362752820720889
                ],
                [
                    103.84935645049902,
                    1.362682483934137
                ],
                [
                    103.84973091592526,
                    1.362406260504349
                ],
                [
                    103.84992386166968,
                    1.362263929416379
                ],
                [
                    103.85137091514449,
                    1.361102941278631
                ],
                [
                    103.85194295836556,
                    1.360652909851773
                ],
                [
                    103.8522672818684,
                    1.360326981650605
                ],
                [
                    103.82714577966834,
                    1.241938910658531
                ],
                [
                    103.82714429349235,
                    1.241945678019855
                ]

            ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "properties": {
        "FMEL_UPD_D": "2014/12/05",
        "INC_CRC": "F6D4903B6C0B72F8",
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "REGION_C": "CR",
        "REGION_N": "CENTRAL REGION",
        "SHAPE_Area": 136405631.404,
        "SHAPE_Leng": 131065.464453,
        "X_ADDR": 27836.5573,
        "Y_ADDR": 31929.9186
    },
    "type": "Feature"
},
{
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    103.82233409716747,
                    1.247288081083765
                ],
                [
                    103.82235533213682,
                    1.247267117084279
                ],
                [
                    103.82236522405806,
                    1.247257351790808
                ],
                [
                    103.82239090120945,
                    1.24726873242952
                ],
                [
                    103.82242101348092,
                    1.247282079176339
                ],
                [
                    103.82244356466394,
                    1.247292075218428
                ],
                [
                    103.8224842992999,
                    1.247310126516275
                ],

                [
                    103.82229812450149,
                    1.247323592638841
                ],
                [
                    103.82233409716747,
                    1.247288081083765
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "properties": {
        "FMEL_UPD_D": "2014/12/05",
        "INC_CRC": "F6D4903B6C0B72F8",
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "REGION_C": "CR",
        "REGION_N": "CENTRAL REGION",
        "SHAPE_Area": 136405631.404,
        "SHAPE_Leng": 131065.464453,
        "X_ADDR": 27836.5573,
        "Y_ADDR": 31929.9186
    },
    "type": "Feature"
},
{
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    103.81270485670082,
                    1.253738883481215
                ],
                [
                    103.81270819925057,
                    1.253736038375202
                ],
                [
                    103.81271747666578,
                    1.25372269002029
                ],
                [
                    103.81272796270179,
                    1.253696608214719
                ],
                [
                    103.81272550089241,
                    1.25367617858827
                ],
                [
                    103.81271663253291,
                    1.253660777180855
                ],
                [
                    103.81268489667742,
                    1.253637281524639
                ],
                [
                    103.81271738240808,
                    1.253596580832204
                ],
                [
                    103.81272993138482,
                    1.25358085854482
                ],
                [
                    103.81277884770714,
                    1.253527980705921
                ],
                [
                    103.81280844732579,
                    1.253491732178708
                ],
                [
                    103.81284783649771,
                    1.253444824881476
                ],
                [
                    103.81289710415396,
                    1.253390129269173
                ],

                [
                    103.81268859863616,
                    1.253749463519217
                ],
                [
                    103.81269418659909,
                    1.253747966839359
                ],
                [
                    103.81269933160983,
                    1.253743587040128
                ],
                [
                    103.81270485670082,
                    1.253738883481215
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "properties": {
        "FMEL_UPD_D": "2014/12/05",
        "INC_CRC": "F6D4903B6C0B72F8",
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "REGION_C": "CR",
        "REGION_N": "CENTRAL REGION",
        "SHAPE_Area": 136405631.404,
        "SHAPE_Leng": 131065.464453,
        "X_ADDR": 27836.5573,
        "Y_ADDR": 31929.9186
    },
    "type": "Feature"
},
{
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    103.81422064298785,
                    1.252570070111331
                ],
                [
                    103.81420878069888,
                    1.252558437176131
                ],
                [
                    103.8142083125649,
                    1.252558523991746
                ],
                [
                    103.81420773751474,
                    1.252557413427196
                ],
                [
                    103.81419024508641,
                    1.252540259301697
                ],
                [
                    103.81418525918728,
                    1.252535369363019
                ],
                [
                    103.81417827319876,
                    1.252525659143691
                ],
                [
                    103.81417483815903,
                    1.252520884975136
                ],
                [
                    103.81417401960785,
                    1.25251974727783
                ],
                [
                    103.8141688845694,
                    1.252512609990775
                ],
                [
                    103.81416372167686,
                    1.252505434720186
                ],
                [
                    103.81415922015667,
                    1.252490646509147
                ],
                [
                    103.81415911592985,
                    1.252490302849641
                ],
                [
                    103.81415883649417,
                    1.252489384917013
                ],
                [
                    103.81415845013613,
                    1.252488116994314
                ],
                [
                    103.8141580341274,
                    1.252486750495618
                ],
                [
                    103.8141581823891,
                    1.252486131910979
                ],
                [
                    103.81415836569447,
                    1.252485366819468
                ],
                [
                    103.81415859033339,
                    1.252484429898899
                ],
                [
                    103.81415863076748,
                    1.252484387394026
                ],
                [
                    103.81415862268139,
                    1.252484294244369
                ],
                [
                    103.81416084480966,
                    1.252475025422944
                ],
                [
                    103.81416187994584,
                    1.25247070708728
                ],
                [
                    103.81416579397985,
                    1.252464651487459
                ],
                [
                    103.81417344413717,
                    1.25245281611786
                ],
                [
                    103.81417638235824,
                    1.25244826989617
                ],
                [
                    103.81418792868888,
                    1.252415206393471
                ],
                [
                    103.81423209597757,
                    1.252398253489821
                ],
                [
                    103.8142345678362,
                    1.252397304828964
                ],
                [
                    103.81423924468973,
                    1.252395510602936
                ],
                [
                    103.8142416716218,
                    1.252394579124685
                ],
                [
                    103.81424197622378,
                    1.252394461559454
                ],
                [
                    103.81424641316956,
                    1.252392758672508
                ],
                [
                    103.81427168974326,
                    1.252383056828959
                ],
                [
                    103.81429695645653,
                    1.252370091131469
                ],
                [
                    103.81430622571014,
                    1.252365335143192
                ],
                [
                    103.81430795807904,
                    1.252364492287584
                ],
                [
                    103.81430790237042,
                    1.252364474199889
                ],
                [
                    103.8143179156083,
                    1.252359335670564
                ],
                [
                    103.81433202075975,
                    1.252352098139711
                ],
                [
                    103.81434014977647,
                    1.252347926362841
                ],
                [
                    103.81435231859189,
                    1.252341681810603
                ],
                [
                    103.81435985727103,
                    1.252338114145249
                ],
                [
                    103.81437420681739,
                    1.25233151509769
                ],
                [
                    103.81439499523958,
                    1.252321955205564
                ],
                [
                    103.81439606179633,
                    1.252321465047431
                ],
                [
                    103.81439624419711,
                    1.252321532876141
                ],
                [
                    103.81440192381508,
                    1.25231876917771
                ],
                [
                    103.81441291824507,
                    1.252313712952395
                ],
                [
                    103.81442976570837,
                    1.252305965378984
                ],
                [
                    103.81444317808666,
                    1.252299726261537
                ],
                [
                    103.81445277979405,
                    1.252295146626335
                ],
                [
                    103.81447443170696,
                    1.252284820742596
                ],
                [
                    103.8144961555022,
                    1.252274461397674
                ],
                [
                    103.81450288101018,
                    1.252271253663335
                ],
                [
                    103.81450281451966,
                    1.252271173174363
                ],
                [
                    103.81452463535528,
                    1.252260878944195
                ],
                [
                    103.81458959107665,
                    1.25223203649656
                ],
                [
                    103.81461125376586,
                    1.252222416920872
                ],
                [
                    103.81464389561143,
                    1.252207399268555
                ],
                [
                    103.81465169486319,
                    1.252203810803814
                ],
                [
                    103.81469601222396,
                    1.252183421305906
                ],
                [
                    103.81472344798394,
                    1.252170002532816
                ],
                [
                    103.81478302601083,
                    1.252140862505733
                ],
                [
                    103.81484031637163,
                    1.252113379257888
                ],
                [
                    103.81490026635718,
                    1.25208846442443
                ],
                [
                    103.81491445851239,
                    1.252102786050432
                ],
                [
                    103.81491771565472,
                    1.252106072536219
                ],
                [
                    103.81491908860134,
                    1.25210674629792
                ],
                [
                    103.81493128425387,
                    1.252117179139818
                ],
                [
                    103.8149446623662,
                    1.2521281301912
                ],
                [
                    103.81496569689162,
                    1.252131490055921
                ],
                [
                    103.81497133065815,
                    1.25213238993891
                ],
                [
                    103.81498839193847,
                    1.252128956184855
                ],
                [
                    103.81500279627888,
                    1.252124305136556
                ],
                [
                    103.8150235712083,
                    1.252116328782531
                ],
                [
                    103.81502467283144,
                    1.252112382141001
                ],
                [
                    103.8150250430265,
                    1.252112184992011
                ],
                [
                    103.81502909456997,
                    1.252100774646097
                ],
                [
                    103.81503503665392,
                    1.252084043029215
                ],
                [
                    103.81503408874394,
                    1.252078647580404
                ],
                [
                    103.81503511578735,
                    1.25207496772605
                ],
                [
                    103.81503518952596,
                    1.252066416954603
                ],
                [
                    103.81502759086356,
                    1.252038774077729
                ],
                [
                    103.81502703827032,
                    1.252038532608371
                ],
                [
                    103.81502617751417,
                    1.252033633656605
                ],
                [
                    103.81501061513713,
                    1.252014397701631
                ],
                [
                    103.81497715415199,
                    1.251984291152084
                ],
                [
                    103.81496625504562,
                    1.251978257151349
                ],
                [
                    103.8149622584071,
                    1.251976044141786
                ],
                [
                    103.8149536020188,
                    1.251971250945737
                ],
                [
                    103.8149359747586,
                    1.25196149181759
                ],
                [
                    103.81491979321531,
                    1.251953915836878
                ],
                [
                    103.8149053934479,
                    1.251947173693286
                ],
                [
                    103.81487481213755,
                    1.251932856472991
                ],
                [
                    103.81486042674678,
                    1.251926121564181
                ],
                [
                    103.8148226958023,
                    1.251918231615303
                ],
                [
                    103.8148209230086,
                    1.251917860813026
                ],
                [
                    103.81482003795891,
                    1.251917765848395
                ],
                [
                    103.8148186775897,
                    1.251917391431592
                ],
                [
                    103.81480645223182,
                    1.251914834704565
                ],
                [
                    103.81478684994318,
                    1.251914215075008
                ],
                [
                    103.81478406270905,
                    1.25191412733175
                ],
                [
                    103.81476586212422,
                    1.251913551121548
                ],
                [
                    103.81475217215036,
                    1.251913118737449
                ],
                [
                    103.81473641375817,
                    1.251913570807558
                ],
                [
                    103.81469760451252,
                    1.25191528611085
                ],
                [
                    103.81464911173373,
                    1.251930252101506
                ],
                [
                    103.81464647993616,
                    1.251931415096138
                ],
                [
                    103.81464604415146,
                    1.251931198949751
                ],
                [
                    103.81463423207276,
                    1.251934844360703
                ],
                [
                    103.81462343982588,
                    1.251938175059867
                ],
                [
                    103.81461634052772,
                    1.251941862105349
                ],
                [
                    103.81459325275814,
                    1.251953853820537
                ],
                [
                    103.81457931114169,
                    1.251961094067155
                ],
                [
                    103.81457055045844,
                    1.251965643864866
                ],
                [
                    103.81450478872569,
                    1.251999797642535
                ],
                [
                    103.81446223335465,
                    1.252023820888956
                ],
                [
                    103.81441832030102,
                    1.2520486110264
                ],
                [
                    103.8143689396795,
                    1.25207648681698
                ],
                [
                    103.81429144309426,
                    1.252119919289534
                ],
                [
                    103.81421839961543,
                    1.252163028029699
                ],
                [
                    103.81418472441868,
                    1.252183801048487
                ],
                [
                    103.81416549402833,
                    1.252195662559566
                ],
                [
                    103.81411929141971,
                    1.252234061560852
                ],
                [
                    103.81407773413764,
                    1.252281223893357
                ],
                [
                    103.81405899059976,
                    1.252313446282806
                ],
                [
                    103.81403917762307,
                    1.252371587767593
                ],
                [
                    103.81403048853925,
                    1.252414490782956
                ],
                [
                    103.81403453146623,
                    1.252476150424537
                ],
                [
                    103.81404507986444,
                    1.252520744745098
                ],
                [
                    103.81406615890175,
                    1.252581120314285
                ],
                [
                    103.81410007800378,
                    1.252628997652677
                ],
                [
                    103.81413071763996,
                    1.252654609498039
                ],
                [
                    103.81415741467501,
                    1.252660750333722
                ],
                [
                    103.81415875168324,
                    1.252661057827697
                ],
                [
                    103.81415903202367,
                    1.252661122944038
                ],
                [
                    103.81416270520218,
                    1.25266196764807
                ],
                [
                    103.81416714302718,
                    1.252662988708921
                ],
                [
                    103.81416796517983,
                    1.252663120752286
                ],
                [
                    103.81420024580622,
                    1.252650676021723
                ],
                [
                    103.8142128693197,
                    1.252638786426654
                ],
                [
                    103.8142159252361,
                    1.252635907855009
                ],
                [
                    103.81421741504606,
                    1.252629051874232
                ],
                [
                    103.81422008102156,
                    1.252623340828278
                ],
                [
                    103.81422398521352,
                    1.252611535275082
                ],
                [
                    103.8142249584107,
                    1.252598998973394
                ],
                [
                    103.81422552184074,
                    1.252591729690962
                ],
                [
                    103.81422064298785,
                    1.252570070111331
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "properties": {
        "FMEL_UPD_D": "2014/12/05",
        "INC_CRC": "F6D4903B6C0B72F8",
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "REGION_C": "CR",
        "REGION_N": "CENTRAL REGION",
        "SHAPE_Area": 136405631.404,
        "SHAPE_Leng": 131065.464453,
        "X_ADDR": 27836.5573,
        "Y_ADDR": 31929.9186
    },
    "type": "Feature"
},

{
    "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    103.74130389714394,
                    1.159976941119677
                ],
                [
                    103.7413428293003,
                    1.159968251449955
                ],
                [
                    103.74129985127891,
                    1.159780169341412
                ],
                [
                    103.74126091912512,
                    1.159788858106384
                ],
                [
                    103.74130389714394,
                    1.159976941119677
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "properties": {
        "FMEL_UPD_D": "2014/12/05",
        "INC_CRC": "11540153B663CA9B",
        "OBJECTID": 5,
        "REGION_C": "WR",
        "REGION_N": "WEST REGION",
        "SHAPE_Area": 257110296.977,
        "SHAPE_Leng": 258264.026231,
        "X_ADDR": 12896.436,
        "Y_ADDR": 33986.5714
    },
    "type": "Feature"
}
]
```

Comment: The original geojson is available @ https://gist.github.com/tekoadjaib/9e0f0729c050b69b283f - but I can't load its Raw format using r.http